# ClassNotFoundException: android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException with OpenCV 3.1.0

Tags: opencv, android-camera, android, opencv3.1

I am working in an android project with Android Studio 2.2 that uses OpenCV 3.1.0 library. I imported the library according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27421494/6305235). The situation is the following:

- When I compile the project for a device with API >= 21 (exactly API 23), everything goes well.
- When I compile the project for a device with API < 21 (exactly API 19, the minimum API that I want to support), I get the following compilation error:

Gradle log

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)...
```

I found these similar questions:

- [Error: package android.hardware.camera2 does not exist OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204781/error-package-android-hardware-camera2-does-not-exist-opencv)
- [Can't import import android.hardware.camera2 classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460972/cant-import-import-android-hardware-camera2-classes)

In both of them the solution was to set the `compileSdkVersion` to minimum 21 (the version where `camera2` API was introduced) and make sure that `build.gradle` files of the project and OpenCV match.

Unfortunately, it does not work for me. I still get the same error. Any idea?

My code is available here: [Github repository](https://github.com/davidmigloz/second-sight).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why you want to set the CompileSdk to such a old State?  Set it to 24 and since you have a MinSdk of 9 the old devices will still be supported (but you need to make sure on runtime that you dont call any camera2 apis)

Comment: The `compileSdkVersion` in both `build.gradle` files is 24. I want to give support from API 19 (KitKat). In the last commit I changed `minSdkVersion` from 19 to 9 just to try (because OpenCV is supposed to give support from API 8, but with `appcompat-v7:24.2.1` the minimum API is 9). But nothing changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: package android.hardware.camera2 does not exist OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204781/error-package-android-hardware-camera2-does-not-exist-opencv)

Comment: @Iuliia As I have explained, the solution proposed in the question that you mention does not solve my problem. I do not have any problem when I am using a device with Android≥5 (`camera2` works well, not as in his case). The problem arrives when I use a device with Android<5, in particular KitKat. `camera2` does not have to be used in that case (because is only for API≥21), but for some reason it is used and that is why my error is thrown.

Comment: I had the same problem and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34061729/323149) answer helped me

Answer (score 6):

Finally, I found a temporal solution thanks to @JavierMollá.

Switching off **Instant Run** solved the issue. Go to `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > InstantRun` and uncheck `Enable Instant Run to hot swap code...`.

[image: Disable instant run]

Instant Run is a major feature of Android Studio, but unfortunately it seems that it is still work-in-progress... As @AndreKR suggests, it can be related with this issue [#212672](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212672).

Comment: So, there was an error during Instant Run preparations and when you switch off Instant Run the error disappears. Whoa! Surprise! -1 for a non-solution.

Comment: @AndreKR Thanks for your better solution. If you read my answer you could see "temporal solution", if you find anything better just tell me, meanwhile I cannot stop working.

Comment: I don't have one, but I suspect it's [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212672). I wasn't suggesting that you stop working, I was suggesting that you delete your "answer" and leave the question open for the time being. Since it's quite obvious that an error in `transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug` will go away when you disable InstantRun, your "answer" does not add any value.

Comment: @AndreKR Thank you for adding info. I've unchecked my answer as correct but I'll leave it there because It's the only temporal solution that I have found for the moment (obvious or not). I will follow up that issue and update my answer as soon as they make any improvement.

Comment: @AndreKR thanks for sharing. That solution worked for me using an Android 4.1.2 device.

Comment: @DavidMiguel Nice!

Comment: @DavidMiguel It worked on 4.4.4 KTU84 P  Redmi HM2LTE-IN