# OpenCV3 error in Camera2Renderer.java

Tags: android, opencv

When I add OpenCV in Android, I am ending up with this error.
Could some one help me with it?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460972/cant-import-import-android-hardware-camera2-classes

Comment: Thanks mate ! with ur help I have resolved the issues !